# QGIS extract part of description to another attribute table column

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have an attribute table with the fields "name" and "desc".
In the "desc" field i have the following string: use:xxx population:xxx.
The xxx are examples given that it is a very large dataset.

I want to extract the xxx after the population to another field called "population" using field calculator.

In the image bellow you can see the real format of the field "desc". My intention is to extract the number in float after the population (just the number).
[image]

Comment: Please provide a few concrete examples of existing data to make tailored answers possible (using, right, left, regex, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract anything after `population=` to the end of line

```
regexp_substr("desc", 'population=(.*)\n')
```

if you want to do calculations, wrap it in a `to_int(...)`

A perfect match for today. Declaring it regexp day :)

Comment: Brilliant... good for me that today is regexp day ! CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string manipulation functions for this, something (untested) like:

```
right(  "DESC",   length( "DESC") - strpos( "DESC", "population:") + length("population:"))
```

to take all the characters to the `RIGHT` of the position of the string `"population:"` - you might want to check my maths on that.

Answer (score 1):

Tested to work in QGIS 2.14. You can search for 'population:' which returns the begin index. You then take the right of the derived start index of the variable in question. The code is then casted in `to_real()` to get your float.

```
 to_real( right("desc", length("desc") - strpos("desc", 'population:') - length('population:') + 1))
```

I needed to ad `+1` to the index.

Edit: if working with QGIS 2.8, use `toreal()` instead of `to_real()`